# Fastapi "AssertionError: Cannot specify multiple `Annotated` FastAPI arguments for 'user'"

Tags: python, backend, fastapi

I currently have a function defined like:

`def user_read(user: UsersTable = Depends(get_current_user)):`

I want to use the Body(embed=True) from [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/#embed-a-single-body-parameter) like:

`def user_read(user: Annotated[UsersTable, Body(embed=True), Depends(get_current_user)]):`

but I am getting the error  "AssertionError: Cannot specify multiple `Annotated` FastAPI arguments for 'user'". I also tried

`def user_read(user: Annotated[UsersTable, Body(embed=True)] = Depends(get_current_user)):`

but that throws this error: "AssertionError: Cannot specify a FastAPI annotation in `Annotated` and `Depends` as a default value together for 'user'"

How can I use Body and Depends together in Fastapi?

I have tried multiple ways to structure the function and to use Depends and Body together, but I cannot seem to make it work. I need to use Body(ember=True) because I require the key as an output.

Comment: `Body` isn't for output models, so what are you actually trying to solve? What does having both `Body()` and `Depends(get_current_user)` mean? What input scenario are you trying to solve? `Depends(get_current_user)` means that it should resolve the value from the function `get_current_user`, but having `Body()` means that it should resolve the value from the Body of the request. Both can't be true at the same time, so do you have an example of what kind of request and problem you're trying to parse?